# Get cursor position in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a custom right click menu in the formula bar (the one that appears when right clicking as you're inside a cell, typing for example). I have managed to get the button I want in my right click, but I can't find how to figure out where the cursor is located inside the cell.

For example, if the cursor is after the 5th character in the cell, how can I determine that either before or during the BeforeRightClick event occurs? The only thing I found was the opposite problem; placing the cursor in a specific part of the cell, using SendKeys:

```
'===================================================================================
'- MOVE CURSOR IN THE FORMULA BAR AS REQUIRED
'- Brian Baulsom September 2007
'===================================================================================
Sub test()
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 3
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Range("A1").Select      ' select cell
    SendKeys "{F2}", True   ' activate formula bar. cursor is to right of contents.
    DoEvents
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '- move cursor 3 characters to the left in the formula bar
    '- or in the cell if Tools/Options/Edit .. "Edit directly in cell" is checked
    SendKeys "{LEFT " & CStr(c) & "}", True         ' ="{LEFT 3}"
    DoEvents
End Sub
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
source: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/282172-setting-cursor-position-cell-text-using-visual-basic-applications.html
```

The end goal is to make it possible to insert some standard substrings while typing in the cell. For example I'd want to insert `[hi this is standard string X-XXX-XXXX]` by using the right click as I type in the cell.

EDIT:

I tried using sendkeys to send my string directly, but I just get a "ping" sound from Excel indicating it's not possible. This was what I had tried:

```
With fbar.Controls.add(Temporary:=True, Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=1)
    .BeginGroup = False
    .FaceId = 267
    .Caption = wsLabels.GetLabel("rcRefMoM")
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'rcAddRef2 '"
End With

Function rcAddRef2()
    SendKeys (" [Ref:X \NAME]")
End Function
```

EDIT 2: Actually it doesn't even enter my rcAddRef2 function at all, it just pings straight away because I'm in edit mode. It doesn't activate a break point if I put one there. So Sendkeys may not be the problem, as much as getting the function to run.

It works fine in the Cell command bar if I try it, so I'm at a loss a bit:

```
'This runs
 With cbar.Controls.add(Temporary:=True, Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=1)
    .BeginGroup = False
    .FaceId = 267
    .Caption = wsLabels.GetLabel("rcRefMoM")
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'rcAddRef2 '"
End With
```

Comment: I just thought of something... could I directly use SendKeys to type the text I want without even ever checking cursor position? Is this considered a robust approach? edit: didn't work

Comment: Is my perception or are you trying to mimic [autocorrect behavior](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/auto_correct2010.php)  somehow?

Comment: I wouldn't consider `SendKeys` a robust approach. Just imagine someone typing while you macro is running. If you require more control as a user is typing why not use a custom form with a textbox? There are all sort of events including `DoubleClick` and `MouseDown` to add predefined text to the current value of the textbox.

Comment: @Sgdva No, I just want to give users the option to enter a predefined substring that requires a standard syntax. I don't expect users to remember the correct sytanx 100% of the time so I figured I would add it to a right click menu so they can insert a reference this way.

Comment: @Ralph I would rather skip this altogether than use a form, it's just users writing in cells. Having a form for every time they want to write in a cell would get ridiculous. The macro is very simple, I don't think anyone would succeed in typing while the macro runs. But I do understand the idea that it's generally a non-robust solution, which is why I'd try to trap the cursor position and insert some string there instead,

Comment: If there's a cursor in the cell, Excel is in edit mode - which means that `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick` won't fire.  If Excel *isn't* in edit mode, there isn't a cursor in the cell at all. You'd probably need to add your own item to the context menu in order to do this.

Comment: @Comintern You're right, I have my button while I right click in edit mode because I had added it on the Double click... It puts it there while entering the cell with dblClick and not when entering using F2. So I DO have a button while in edit mode; but it turns out I can't use it? I'm not sure I understand correctly.

Comment: Interesting - I'm guessing it's because Excel locks down pretty hard when it's in edit mode.  It does pretty much the same thing when you try to access the VBE while the formula bar is active.  It's kind of like it treats interactions there as modal.

Comment: @DavidG Precisely my point, why don't you try autorrector and use keywords? IE:  Set your standard word let's say "ms1" and set the word to be replaced as "Microsoft-Systems-01-900-100" whenever they type "my text desired ms1" when hitting enter it would be "my text desired Microsoft-Systems-01-900-100". In your right click -already defined- you could add the hints for the abbreviations instead, [see this image](https://s20.postimg.io/ynwff30ot/try.gif)

Comment: @Sgdva Not exactly what I was looking for but it's a creative way to get around the problem, that's for sure! I will consider it.

Comment: Could you use send keys to shift+home and then copy the text, then compare the copied text with what was in the cell to determine the cell position? (although I agree sendkeys is not robust)

Comment: @Cody No code will even run when I click the button. It gets added to the Formula Bar but clicking it just closes the right click menu and a "ping!" is heard, the same kind when you are writing in a cell and then try to use the VBE without getting out of the cell first.

Comment: Seems to me like you would be better of using a drop down list in the cells that would need user input. Check this link out: [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/autocomplete-validation.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Once you're in cell edit mode you don't have events being fired into VBA.  Although there might be some deeper Windows dll code you could insert, a much better option would be to use a UserForm with a TextBox object:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.textbox.aspx

Specifically, you want to intercept the TextChanged event:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx

There are a few dozen events triggered on that Object, including KeyDown, KeyPress, and KeyUp so I'm sure you can find whatever is best for your scenario.